# Button not submiting via Jquery .click() event

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I am having some very strange behaviour in IE with my .Net buttons.

I have a normal HTML button.

```
    <input type="submit" onclick="return Valadation()" value="Save profile" class="btn primary rounded" />
```

Which then calls some simple JavaScript

```
   if (txbEmail.length == 0) {
          $("[id$='txbEmail']").addClass("error");
          $("[id$='txbEmail']").focus().select();
          showMessage = true;
          displayMessage += "Email Address, "
    }
    else {
         $("[id$='txbEmail']").removeClass("error");
    }

    if (showMessage) {ShowStatus("warning", displayMessage);
    return false;
    }
    else {
   var saveButton = $('[id*="butSave"]');
   saveButton.focus();
   saveButton.click();
```

}

With the final result clicking a asp.net button

```
<asp:Button ID="butSave" runat="server" Style="display: none;" onclick="butSave_Click" />
```

This issue is that Ie just wont ever post the page back? works fine on FF, Chrome, just not IE

Comment: does it show any script error ?

Comment: You can't focus hidden element. Just remove the `saveButton.focus();` line. Probably FF and Chrome graciously ignore this while IE crash with error, thus not getting to the line afterwards..

Comment: Finally figured out what's happening. the blank input field is submitting the form before click event in IE, any ideas how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issues within jQuery and wont be fixed, but there is a very easy work around.

The script .click() will not work if the button in question has the type="submit" (only in IE wont this work IE7,IE8,IE9 all show this error).

But if you just change the button type to type="button" the .click() event works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the ASP button to perform javascript validation, use the OnClientClick property:

```
<asp:Button ID="butSave" runat="server" Style="display: none;" onclientclick="return Valadation()" onclick="butSave_Click" />
```

Simply return false from your Valadation() method to stop the asp button from submitting.

Comment: Tried this didn't work, but I did finally find the error within the jQuery forum. I have added an answer to fix this issue.